# MERN app crashed when Mongo DB id in request is not equal to 24 stamps

Tags: mongodb

I accidentally got a problem in the Mern application: if you enter a link in the address bar of the browser or Postman, which is not equal to 24 characters of Mongo DB id, the application completely stops working

http://localhost:3000/api/listing/update/65d79a91987bab1111111 - the length of id is not equal to 24 characters

```
Query: [Function (anonymous)] {
      base: {
        toConstructor: [Function: toConstructor],
        setOptions: [Function (anonymous)],
        collection: [Function: collection],
        collation: [Function (anonymous)],
        '$where': [Function (anonymous)],
        where: [Function (anonymous)],
        equals: [Function: equals],
        eq: [Function: eq],
        or: [Function: or],
        nor: [Function: nor],
        and: [Function: and],
        gt: [Function (anonymous)],
        gte: [Function (anonymous)],
        lt: [Function (anonymous)],
        lte: [Function (anonymous)],
        ne: [Function (anonymous)],
        in: [Function (anonymous)],
        nin: [Function (anonymous)],
        all: [Function (anonymous)],
        regex: [Function (anonymous)],
        size: [Function (anonymous)],
        maxDistance: [Function (anonymous)],
        minDistance: [Function (anonymous)],
        mod: [Function (anonymous)],
        exists: [Function (anonymous)],
        elemMatch: [Function (anonymous)],
        within: [Function: within],
        box: [Function (anonymous)],
        polygon: [Function (anonymous)],
        circle: [Function (anonymous)],
        near: [Function: near],
        intersects: [Function: intersects],
        geometry: [Function: geometry],
        select: [Function: select],
        slice: [Function (anonymous)],
        sort: [Function (anonymous)],
        limit: [Function (anonymous)],
        skip: [Function (anonymous)],
        batchSize: [Function (anonymous)],
        comment: [Function (anonymous)],
        maxTimeMS: [Function (anonymous)],
        maxTime: [Function (anonymous)],
        hint: [Function (anonymous)],
        j: [Function: j],
        slaveOk: [Function (anonymous)],
        setReadPreference: [Function (anonymous)],
        read: [Function (anonymous)],
        r: [Function (anonymous)],
        readConcern: [Function (anonymous)],
        tailable: [Function (anonymous)],
        w: [Function: writeConcern],
        writeConcern: [Function: writeConcern],
        wTimeout: [Function: wtimeout],
        wtimeout: [Function: wtimeout],
        merge: [Function (anonymous)],
        find: [Function (anonymous)],
        _find: [AsyncFunction: _find],
        cursor: [Function (anonymous)],
        findOne: [Function (anonymous)],
        _findOne: [AsyncFunction: _findOne],
        count: [Function (anonymous)],
        _count: [AsyncFunction: _count],
        distinct: [Function (anonymous)],
        _distinct: [AsyncFunction: _distinct],
        updateMany: [Function: updateMany],
        _updateMany: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
        updateOne: [Function: updateOne],
        _updateOne: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
        replaceOne: [Function: replaceOne],
        _replaceOne: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
        deleteOne: [Function (anonymous)],
        _deleteOne: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
        deleteMany: [Function (anonymous)],
        _deleteMany: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
        findOneAndUpdate: [Function (anonymous)],
        _findOneAndUpdate: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
        findOneAndDelete: [Function (anonymous)],
        findOneAndRemove: [Function (anonymous)],
        _findOneAndRemove: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
        setTraceFunction: [Function (anonymous)],
        exec: [AsyncFunction: exec],
        then: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
        selected: [Function: selected],
        selectedInclusively: [Function: selectedInclusively],       
        selectedExclusively: [Function: selectedExclusively],       
        _mergeUpdate: [Function (anonymous)],
        _optionsForExec: [Function (anonymous)],
        _fieldsForExec: [Function (anonymous)],
        _updateForExec: [Function (anonymous)],
        _ensurePath: [Function (anonymous)],
        _validate: [Function (anonymous)]
      }
    },
    '$init': Promise { undefined, catch: [Function (anonymous)] },  
    '$caught': true,
    [Symbol(mongoose#Model)]: true
  }
}

Node.js v20.11.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem:

```
export const updateListing = async (req, res, next) => {
    const lengthId = req.params.id.length;
    console.log(lengthId)
    if (lengthId !== 24) {
        return next(errorHandler(404, "id length is incorrect"));
    }
}
```